# What to do when the site doesn't accept my question?

Tags: discussion, support, quality-filter

I am trying to ask a question on the main site, the solution of which I cannot find after innumerable tries. I've provided my working and used proper grammar, but the system keeps saying, "This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar." How do I ask?

How do I prove this?
$5e = 1 + 2^3/2! + 3^3/3! + 4^3/4!+ ... $ 
 Any hints for the proof is appreciated.

I've tried writing it as:
$RHS=1+4+3^2/2!+4^2/3!+... = 5+ (10-1)/2! + (15+1)/3! +...=5(1+2/2!+3/3!+...)+(-1/2!+1/3!+...)$
However, I'm unable to proceed any further from here. Can anyone help?

Edit: I found the almost duplicate. Hence, got the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question here to include the text that you are trying to post as a question on the main site?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've edited it.

Comment: It would help a lot if you rewrote it using more proper formatting, e.g. fractions and equation alignment. A MathJax reference is here -- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It would also help if you add text to the body, not just MathJax.

Comment: It would also help if you search for a duplicate, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000506/how-to-find-sum-of-n3-n-when-n-goes-from-0-to-infinity

Comment: That "does not meet our quality standards" message may appear when the body of the question is very short.  And MathJax is counted as zero when the system computes the length of the question.  So: as Asaf said, add text to the question.  That may be enough that the question will be allowed.